# Check if a value in a range for a specific key is less than / more than a number

Tags: excel

I have two columns in Excel.
KEY and AMT

```
KEY         AMT
DATEID_1    200
DATEID_2    6142
DATEID_1    9700
DATEID_2    4500
```

What I need to work out is for each key 
- if the sum of that key's amount in the entire table is greater than 10000 
- but the individual amounts within the key are ALL less than 10000.

So, supposed output for the above would be

```
KEY         AMT     FLAG
DATEID_1    200     OK   
DATEID_2    6142    NOT OK 
DATEID_1    9700    OK
DATEID_2    4500    NOT OK
```

OK for DATEID_1 because

```
9700 + 200 = 9900 which is less than 10000 
but each amount less than 10000
```

NOT OK for DATEID_2 because

```
6142 + 4500 = 10642 which is greater than 10000 
but each amount less than 10000
```

Hope I was clear enough. I can't use VBA.

EDIT : Doesn't work for the below with @Alexis Olson formula.

`KEY         AMT
DATEID_3    26950
DATEID_3    26950
DATEID_4    38000`

Answer (score 1):

To get this:

```
KEY         AMT     FLAG
DATEID_1    200     OK   
DATEID_2    6142    NOT OK 
DATEID_1    9700    OK
DATEID_2    4500    NOT OK
```

You just need to put your conditions together with an `AND`

```
=IF(AND(MAX(B:B*(A:A=A2))<10000,SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B)<10000),"OK","NOT OK")
```

This takes the maximum value where the `KEY` matches your current row `KEY` and checks if it is less than 10000 and uses `SUMIF` to add up all the `AMT` with matching `KEY` and checks if that is less than 10000.

Note that this is an array formula, so it should be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This reproduces your given output. However, I'm not sure your stated output is what you meant. Assuming your `AMT` column contains positive values, then your first condition is redundant since summing to less than 10000 implies each individual one is less than 10000.

Comment: Indeed, you are correct, my first statement is redundant, essentially, I just wanted to highlight two scenarios. 
I will try this and let you know, thanks.

Comment: Hey I did try it, worked for some but still doesn't work for some like the below

`KEY         AMT
DATEID_3 26950
DATEID_3 26950
DATEID_4 38000
`
Ideally for the above it should be returning OK but it returns NOT OK for some reason, cant seem to figure it out.